# How can I align a <svg> element with text?

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4, alignment

I wanted to use Bootstrap icons next to text to help differentiate options/items in a simple webpage I'm designing, but the `<svg>` elements are slightly off relatively to the text. I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0 with a personal css file to tweak a couple of things.

Both the HTML and CSS I used are in https://www.codeply.com/p/MU4zE84NJc, where the problem can be seen in the table items. It's minimal but I can't leave it unsolved.

Any idea how can I make sure the `<svg>` elements stay aligned with the text?

Comment: Could you provide the code here instead, please? Preferably in a snippet.

Comment: I didn't provide a snippet because it was too much code imo, will do next time. Anyway, it's solved already, thanks for the interest :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using "**vertical-align**" property to **svg** element.

Like text-bottom, text-top

```css
svg {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: The "text-top" managed to fix it, thank you so so much :3